# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql (tomcat doesn't see CLASSPATH)

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, tomcat8

I am trying to run a program with connection to MySQL database but I get the error "No suitable driver found".

/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/setenv.sh

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
CLASSPATH=/opt/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar
```

a part of my code:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
...
...
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            out.println("error: class not found <br>");
        }
        con = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mybase", "root", "123456");
        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            out.println("Error message:" + sqlEx.getMessage());
            out.println("error: connection to database <br>");
            if (con != null) {
                try { con.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { }
            }
            return;
        }
```

When it runs I have an error:

```
error: class not found 
Error message:No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mybase error: connection to database
```

I suppose, tomcat8 doesn't get CLASSPATH variable, for some reason.

Comment: You need to put that JDBC JAR in the Tomcat server /lib folder.  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db is the URL format; yours looks right.  The fact is that all Java EE app servers that I know of do not depend on a CLASSPATH environment variable.

Comment: Tomcat is far more complex than your bog-standard Java application in all sorts of ways; one of which is the very complex classloading required by Java EE. You need to read the documentation to understand what's going on; but you either need to place your library into Tomcat's `/lib` location or into your `.war's` `/lib` location.

Comment: I moved my /opt/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar to the /usr/share/tomcat8/lib and commented line with CLASSPATH in the setenv.sh file, then restarted tomcat. No changes, I see that error.

Comment: How are you deploying to tomcat? Spring or another? The jdbc drivers need to be placed in beans.xml or the sort

Comment: I just put .war file to the tomcat's webapps dir. I have tomcat and java only.

Comment: Have you tried to include the driver inside the war? Tomcat probably assumes that jars will be included inside a war file

Comment: If this works let me know, I will write as an answer